# Who is the guy on the left in this collage poster? And which anime is he from?

Tags: gungrave

I saw this guy on a poster with Beyond the Grave and Trigun's main protagonist. But I can't find who he is, nor whether he has his own anime.

The guy is on the left, wielding two crimson swords, with gray hair.

[image]

Comment: A bit of a side note: The man on the left isn't actually the protagonist of Trigun. He is from the second game (like Juji), and his name is Rocketbilly Redcadillac.

Comment: You probably meant right, not left =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is Juji Kabane from Gungrave: Overdose - That's the second game, not actually an anime.
The weapons are actually Gunblades, if you look at the hilts of the swords in your image you can kinda see the guns.

[image]